# Showing a polynomial is of degree $N$ at most

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, polynomials

I found the following exercise in my calculus notes:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ and $f^{(k)}\equiv 0$ for all $k\geq N$ Use Taylor's formula to show that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $N$ at most.

I've been trying to solve the previous exercise but I don't really know how to start. Any help is appreciated

Comment: How to start: Write down Taylor's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$-th term of the Taylor series centered at $a$, by Taylor's theorem, is $f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k/k!=0$, for all $k\ge N$.  The function is real analytic (equals its Taylor series), and we can actually say it is a polynomial of degree at most $N-1$.